# cacheManager.getCache always return null but the value is in cacheManager bean when inspect the object

Tags: spring-boot, spring-cache

I'm trying to use Spring Cache to store data, generated by another method inside Service class.

This method marked with @Cacheable is a public method, the cache is being called in Controller layer.

When I do debugging, I inspect the object cacheManager, I found that it contains the map that I stored, but when calling the method `cacheManager.getCache("cache")` it return null.

Question is why that method return null while the object is holding the value?

This is the config, service and controller:
Spring bean config:

```
@EnableCaching
public class CachingConfig {

    @Bean
    public CacheManager cacheManager() {
        return new ConcurrentMapCacheManager("optCache");
    }
}
```

Service:

```
public void verify(Request request, String authorization) {
        String memberId = parseAuthToken(authorization).getMembershipID();
        buildOtpCache(memberId, request.getTokenUUID(), 0)
    }

    @Cacheable("otpCache")
    public OTPCache buildOtpCache(String memberId, String uuid, int counter) {
        return OTPCache.builder()
            .memberId(memberId)
            .tokenUUID(uuid)
            .timestamp(LocalDateTime.now())
            .counter(counter)
            .build();
    }
```

Controller:

```
@Override
    public void verifyOTP(MeOTPVerifyRequest verifyOTPRequest, String authorization) {
        String memberId = parseAuthToken(authorization).getMembershipID();
        Collection<String> a = cacheManager.getCacheNames();
        OTPCache OTPCache = cacheManager.getCache("cache").get(memberId, OTPCache.class);
        otpService.verify(verifyOTPRequest, authorization);
    }
```

EDIT:

This is my new service class, remove @Cacheable annotation:

```
public void verify(Request request, String authorization) {
        String memberId = parseAuthToken(authorization).getMembershipID();
        cacheManager.getCache("optCache").put(memberId, buildOtpCache(memberId, request.getTokenUUID(), 0));
    }

    public OTPCache buildOtpCache(String memberId, String uuid, int counter) {
        return OTPCache.builder()
            .memberId(memberId)
            .tokenUUID(uuid)
            .timestamp(LocalDateTime.now())
            .counter(counter)
            .build();
    }
```

Comment: Internal method call doesn't go through the proxy so more or less the `@Cacheable` is useless.

Comment: I refactor the service, same exception is still thrown!! What could be the reason?

Comment: You are getting/using different caches... `optCache` in one and `cache` in the other.